# next year prediction based on data of previous years using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, large-data

For my project in R, I took 5 years(2011-2015) of socio-economic data from different cities in the US, and using this data, I want to predict the amount of births in the year of 2016(I have the data of it) using R. For that I have a couple of questions:

1) the socio-economic data is counted by % out of the whole city population but the births data are in amount of births. I don't believe it will affect the model but it wouldn't hurt to ask if it will?

2) the 5 year data is organized in 5 tables- I can merge them with R but I don't know if it's best to merge by city(meaning I will have 5 times the columns, I honestly don't know whether that's a good idea), or a situation in which I have 5 times the rows(each city has 5 rows corresponding to each year), which will be a good organizing method?

3) should I pay attention to the total population(though the data is in % out of population so I don't think it will increase each year) and the years themselves(add a column of years), or it doesn't really matter for the train/test methods?

4) should I include the data for 2016(the whole socio-economic data for the year I'm trying to predict)? or should I only include the births?

I'm basically trying to first check if there are connections between any of the predictors so that I will have a better idea of which model I should pick, then I can backstep or forwardstep to get rid of some of the predictors for a smaller model. I also want to know whether the train-test should come before I assume a model(for generalization, this question is connected to my 4th question about including the 2016 data). Any additional guidelines for a beginner like me will be gladly accepted.

Attached are some of the columns(predictors) that I want to use, and how the data looks for each table(each representing 1 year).

[image: head(data)]

[image: head(data)more]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give some input to your 4 questions.

1) As long as it is the same format for each feature/column, it is fine to have different units in different columns. However, make sure to normalize your columns if you are using an algorithm that is sensitive to scale. In general, I'd always do it, even if you are using an insensitive algorithm.

2) Here, it is mostly about trying it all and see what is best. But if you are worried about having to many features, which could be a valid worry, then you could use a summary statistics across the year like the mean or median. However, bear in mind that the most recent years might be the most predictive and you would lose that information in using the mean or median. You could instead try only by using the most recent year and then by maybe using something like the most recent year and the rates (ratios) between the most recent year and the most recent yea - 1 (or the least recent year, you can try both) for each feature. This is because this trend should be useful in order to capture the social trends of the cities.

3) I would keep the population, does not cost anything to do so. And the year could matter so I would also keep it. However, if you use something like the rate I talked about between two years, then specifying the year should not matter.

4) Finally, This entirely depends on your goal. Probably all these statistics are available at the same moment. So if your goal is to predict the amount of births in 2016, I would not include the data from 2016. Since if you had access to this data it means you would also know the response you are trying to predict, making your work pointless. So do not use the data in my opinion.

Hope this helps

Edits: Yes, leave the data from 2016 out. If you use 5 rows for each year, then you have to include the name of the city as a predictor, otherwise your model will not be able to take the trend over the years. But I think this is an odd way of doing it. I'd rather keep the name of the city simply as an index and not use it as a predictor. Essentially you want your model to be city agnostic and that you could apply to any city for which you have the same data collected. If I were you, I would either try something like either the most recent year + the rate for each feature from most recent year to previous year. In that case you would not have to include year as a predictor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

I wanted to ask more about the connection of question 2 to 3 in regards to training and test when modeling- I should not account for year 2016 at all then, and just look at what I have- if I work with an additional column of "year", how do I incorporate that in the model(as a predictor?) and in the train-test? let's say that if I make 5 rows for each city(each year), it looks to me like the city itself won't matter if I don't account for the year too, and it will just be another piece of information. then do I make the model unique by looking at cities(+years)? how?

Comment: See my edit in the answer above